# How To Apply Indexing In MySql Using Join

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am not very familiar with indexing . I am applying indexing on records because it is taking very much time to find results on tables . The query is working fine

```
SELECT words.wordid, synsets.synsetid, pos, definition
FROM words, senses, synsets
WHERE words.wordid = senses.wordid
AND senses.synsetid = synsets.synsetid
AND lemma='apple'


| wordid | lemma               |                       
+--------+--------------------+-
|  1     | Apply               |
|  2     | PRIMARY             |
|  3     | DEPENDENT           |
+----+--------------------+-----
```

Other table

---

```
wordid  casedwordid  synsetid  senseid  sensenum    laxid   tagcount
1         19        108659519   1       1       0   0
2       1-hitter    108970180   2       1       0   0
3        NULL       104510146   5       1       0   0
```

3rd Table of Synsets

### Senses table

---

```
synsetid   pos     lexdomainid  definition
108659519   n       3   that which is perceived or known or inferred to have its
108970180   n       3   an entity that has physical existance   
104510146   n       3   a general concept formed by extracting common features
```

The sql query is working correct but now i have to apply indexing to get far more faster results than simple query.

How I can apply indexing on these three table

Answer (score 0):

If you run only SELECT like this then

```
SELECT words.wordid, synsets.synsetid, pos, definition
    FROM words, senses, synsets
    WHERE words.wordid = senses.wordid
    AND senses.synsetid = synsets.synsetid
    AND lemma='apple'
```

You need these indexes (see more in manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html):

```
-- create simple b tree indexes for int fields (improve join performance)
CREATE INDEX words_wordid ON words (wordid);
CREATE INDEX senses_wordid ON senses (wordid);
CREATE INDEX senses_synsetid ON senses (synsetid);
CREATE INDEX synsets_synsetid ON synsets (synsetid);

-- we create an index using the first 20 characters of the lemma
CREATE INDEX words_lemma ON synsets (lemma(20));
```

If you want to run another select queries then you should add more indexes to improve select performance:)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's use the `JOIN..ON` syntax:

```
SELECT  words.wordid, synsets.synsetid, pos, definition
    FROM  words
    JOIN  senses ON words.wordid = senses.wordid
    JOIN  synsets ON senses.synsetid = synsets.synsetid
    WHERE  words.lemma='apple'
```

Now, we can see that the only thing useful in the `WHERE` clause is `words.lemma`.  So, let's have this for `words`:

```
INDEX(lemma)
```

Once `words` has been looked into for apples, the next table to go to is `senses`.  Now that table needs:

```
INDEX(wordid)
```

Finally to get into `synsets` efficiently, have

```
INDEX(synsetid)
```

Based on the column name, I would *guess* that `synsetid` is already the `PRIMARY KEY`.  Remember that a `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key which is an `INDEX`.  So, if it is the PK, don't add the `INDEX` I suggest.

[Cookbook on indexing](http://localhost/misc/index_cookbook_mysql).